# Ionic 2 cannot read object property in view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm doing a tutorial with Ionic 2 and sometimes I can't access to my
object property in the view.
For example:

```
// Typescript file
export class MyClass {
     myObject: any;

     constructor() { }

     ionViewDidLoad() {
         this.myObject = getData(...);
     }
}

// HTML
<p>{{ myObject.property }}<p>
```

The result is: 
"Cannot read property 'property' of undefined at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass..."

I can log my object which contains its property.
Also if I try this:

```
<p>{{ myObject | json }}</p>
```

My json object is displayed with its property...
I just can't access my property with the interpolation brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're receiving the response from somewhere `getData(...)` and it (maybe) takes too long, as consequence, template tries to access the property(ies) of an **undefined** object.

In order to solve this *"issue"*, use the [**`Safe Navigation Operator`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) for safe navigation:

```
<p>{{ myObject?.property }}</p>
```